# NodeJs with Express: How to redirect from app.post() in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, redirect

i am trying to call another app.get by redirecting this submit post. but the problem is that i am getting an error saying that

"res.redirect is not a function".

below is the code for reference. i am unable to detect why is this error coming. it would be really helpful if someone can figure this out.
Thankyou

```
app.post('/submit', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  var sql = "insert into `members` (`email`, `type`, `name`, `uid`) values ('"+ req.body.email +"', '"+ req.body.type +"', '"+req.body.name+"', '"+req.body.uid+"')";
    db.query(sql, (err, res1) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (req.body.type == 'student') {
            res.redirect('/student');  
        } else {
            res.redirect('/teacher');
        }
    })  
})
```

both '/student' and '/teacher' are get requests. for reference:

```
app.get('/student', (req, res) => {
    res.render('studentHome');
})
```

Comment: Please don't write `if (err) throw err;` as that doesn't do anything useful.  You need to send an error response, not throw in that case.

Comment: Your code should work just fine as shown.  Are you 200% sure that you haven't redefined `res` somehow like perhaps `db.query(sql, (err, res) => {` because that's what your error message would be consistent with?

Comment: yes, u r right. In my second db.query in my code, i have used res, so it has overwritten that. Thankyou so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error sounds like you have refined the symbol `res` so that it isn't the `res` from the `app.post()` callback arguments, but rather some other `res`.  It seems that perhaps your actual code is this:

```
app.post('/submit', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  var sql = "insert into `members` (`email`, `type`, `name`, `uid`) values ('"+ req.body.email +"', '"+ req.body.type +"', '"+req.body.name+"', '"+req.body.uid+"')";
    db.query(sql, (err, res) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (req.body.type == 'student') {
            res.redirect('/student');  
        } else {
            res.redirect('/teacher');
        }
    })  
})
```

Where the `res` in this `db.query(sql, (err, res) => {` overrides the higher scoped `res` in `app.post('/submit', (req, res) => {` and you get the wrong `res` when you try to do `res.redirect()`.

The fix is to make sure you use a different argument name in `db.query(sql, (err, qres) => {`.  Since the code in your actual question shows `res1` as that argument, that code should work as you show, but apparently that's not what is in your actual code.

Answer (score -1):

because you have left a "}" of the post route and you have a extra "})"

it should be

```
app.post('/submit', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  var sql = "insert into `members` (`email`, `type`, `name`, `uid`) values ('"+ req.body.email +"', '"+ req.body.type +"', '"+req.body.name+"', '"+req.body.uid+"')";
    db.query(sql, (err, res1) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (req.body.type == 'student') {
            res.redirect('/student');  
        } else {
            res.redirect('/teacher');
        } 
})
}
```

Comment: This is not a correct analysis.  The bracing in the OP's code is correct.

Comment: That '}' is left from pasting here... but it is there in the actual code in my editor